# Connecting the data to my code using d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to simply use the data that a have in my array, the goal is when the if statement is executed it prints the index of that array. so example for the first if as to print index[0] -> 12, the second if should be index[1] -> 1 etc... As of right now everything is hard coded and does display what i need but I would like to come from the data set.

here is the full code: http://plnkr.co/edit/JqACszHaWNy7mKxXl3V1?p=preview

```
var setTimeDeg;
var timeControl = 0;

var data = ["12", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"]; 

if (timeControl >=0 && timeControl < 30)
  {
     setTimeDeg = 0;

    clockGroup.append("text")
       .attr("x", "110")
       .attr("y", "50")
     //.data(data)
     //.enter()
       .text(function(d,i) { return i[0];  });
     //.text("12 to 1");
   } 

 else if (timeControl >=30 && timeControl < 60)
  {
     setTimeDeg = 30;

     clockGroup.append("text")
       .attr("x","110")
       .attr("y","50")
       .text("1 to 2");
     //.text(function(d,i) { return i + " to 2";  });
  }

  else if (timeControl >=60 && timeControl < 90)
  {
      setTimeDeg = 60;

     clockGroup.append("text")
      .attr("x","110")
      .attr("y","50")
      .text("2 to 3");
  }

  else if (timeControl >= 90 && timeControl < 120)
  {
      setTimeDeg = 90;

     clockGroup.append("text")
      .attr("x","110")
      .attr("y","50")
      .text("3 to 4");
  }

  else if (timeControl >= 120 && timeControl < 150)
  {
     setTimeDeg = 120;

     clockGroup.append("text")
     .attr("x","110")
     .attr("y","50")
     .text("4 to 5");
  }

  else if (timeControl >= 150 && timeControl < 180)
  {
      setTimeDeg = 150;

     clockGroup.append("text")
      .attr("x","110")
      .attr("y","50")
      .text("5 to 6");
  }

  else if (timeControl >= 180 && timeControl < 210)
  {
     setTimeDeg = 180;

     clockGroup.append("text")
       .attr("x","110")
      .attr("y","50")
      .text("6 to 7");
  }

  else if (timeControl >= 210 && timeControl < 240)
  {
      setTimeDeg = 210;

      clockGroup.append("text")
       .attr("x","110")
       .attr("y","50")
       .text("7 to 8");
  }

 else if (timeControl >= 240 && timeControl < 270)
  {
     setTimeDeg = 240;

     clockGroup.append("text")
        .attr("x","110")
        .attr("y","50")
        .text("8 to 9");
  }

 else if (timeControl >= 270 && timeControl < 300)
  {
       setTimeDeg = 270;

       clockGroup.append("text")
        .attr("x","110")
        .attr("y","50")
       .text("9 to 10");
  }

  else if (timeControl >= 300 && timeControl < 330)
  {
        setTimeDeg = 300;

          clockGroup.append("text")
              .attr("x","110")
              .attr("y","50")
              .text("10 to 11");
  }

  else if (timeControl >= 330 && timeControl < 360)
  {
         setTimeDeg = 330;

         clockGroup.append("text")
             .attr("x","110")
             .attr("y","50")
             .text("11 to 12");
  }

  else if (timeControl >= 360)
  {
      setTimeDeg = 0;
  }

   var arc = d3.svg
     .arc()
     .innerRadius(0)
     .outerRadius(radius)
     .startAngle((setTimeDeg * Math.PI) / 180)
     .endAngle(((setTimeDeg + 30) * Math.PI) / 180);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you are simply deriving two values (your array index and `setTimeDeg`) from the incoming `timeControl` value. Start by calculating those values using the `floor` and `modulo` functions:

```
var minTimeDeg = 30;
var hourIndex = Math.floor((timeControl % 360) / minTimeDeg);
var setTimeDeg = hourIndex * minTimeDeg;
```

Your `x` and `y` attributes are fixed, so the only other data that varies is the text itself. But since its format is always `<this hour> to <next hour>`, this string can also be derived from the array index that was previously calculated. Use the index to lookup this hour and the next, with something like:

```
var thisHour = data[hourIndex];
var nextHour = data[(hourIndex+1) % data.length];
```

*When looking up the next hour, use the "%" modulo operator to wrap around to the beginning of the array -- otherwise you will get an "out of bounds" exception when this hour reaches the end of the array.*

So now you can eliminate all the if/else conditions, along with their boilerplate code. Use these variables in one common D3 code block to build your display...